# SYSENTER Syntax error

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, masm

Why does the following code produce syntax error at *sysenter* insturction? How could it be modified for making the simplest kernel mode transition?

```
.586p
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

.code
main proc

  mov eax,18ch    
  mov edx,esp
  sysenter

main endp
end main
```

Comment: `.586p` means _"Enables assembly of all instructions (including privileged) for the **Pentium** processor."_ Are you sure that `sysenter` is available on a regular old Pentium?

Comment: It doesn't work with `.386p`, `.486p` or `.686p` either

Comment: What assembler are you using?

Comment: MASM with qeditor or Winasm

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with MASM. I get `error A2085:instruction or register not accepted in current CPU mode` instead. If I delete the `.586p` line your code assembles without error.

Comment: I get 15 errors if I remove `.586p` and `error A2008: syntax error : sysenter` otherwise. What could be the problem?

Comment: You're probably using a version of MASM that doesn't support the `sysenter` instruction. MASM 6.14.8444 (which came with MASM32) doesn't seem to support it, while MASM 12.00.31101.0 (which came with Visual Studio Express 12.0) does.

Comment: That seems to work. Is there a way to do away without using Visual Studio?

Comment: Use NASM instead? (I haven't checked if it supports `sysenter`, but I'm assuming it does)

Comment: @user1232138 Another option is to encode the machine instructions that masm may not understand as `db` or `dw` directive entries. For instance replace `sysenter` with `dw 340fh` . `sysexit` could be coded as `dw 350fh` instead.

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags to your posts.

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of *MASM* may not support all instructions even though they may be valid for a particular architecture. This is the case with *MASM32* and usage of `sysenter` and `sysexit`. Your options would be to:

1. Use a more modern version of *MASM* from Visual Studio. You can download the free Express versions of VS which contain a modern *MASM* assembler.
2. Use a different assembler like *NASM* that supports the instructions you want
3. Use *MASM32* as is but encode the instructions as byte or words directly. You can replace the 2 byte `sysenter` instruction with `dw 340fh`, and replace `sysexit` with `dw 350fh`. The OP code information for these instructions can be found [here](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_313.html) and [here](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_314.html)

Comment: I made this answer a community wiki as i felt the original question was a good one and I wanted to provide a useful answer based on the comments by a number of individuals